# Easy way to get logs from Graylog2 on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graylog2

I'm logging my Rails app needs to graylog2 server, using Yell gem, and/or gelf-rb.

I've searched a lot on the web on how to access these logs from my app, using some custom fields to filter, but no luck yet.

The only access i have to these messages are from graylog webserver. But I need it from my app. My users need to see some of these messages inside app.

There is something similar to activerecord to query and retrieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use for example [Tire](https://github.com/karmi/tire#activemodel-integration) to access the Greylog's Elasticsearch database.

Comment: Seems a interesting way, already testing. ElasticSearch is new for me, so thanks for the tip.